# Find file details and include M5SUM/SHA1SUM

Tags: awk

Disclaimer: I'm new to awk.

Question: How can I sort the find command's output and add a md5sum too--all using awk?

**My attempt:**

```
find $1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat --format '%Y :%y %n' | sort -nr | awk 'BEGIN { ORS=" "} {print $1,$2,$3,$4} {system("md5sum $4")} '
```

Problem: same md5sum!

```
2015-12-21 12:41:54.000000000 -0600 ./gsk8capicmd_64 d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  -
2015-12-21 12:41:53.000000000 -0600 ./gsk8ver d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  -
2015-12-21 12:41:52.000000000 -0600 ./gsk8ver_64 d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  -
2015-12-21 12:41:52.000000000 -0600 ./gsk8capicmd d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  -
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `find $1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat --format '%Y :%y %n' | sort -nr` alone? a few lines for sample?

Comment: Is the file part of column 5 or column 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the file-name part you are trying to do `md5sum` comprises the `$5` of the piped output, just use the `Awk` part alone as

```
awk '{ cmd = "md5sum "$5; while ( ( cmd | getline md5result ) > 0 ) { print  $1,$2,$3,$4,md5result } ; close(cmd)} '
```

Comment: I didn't realize that I could just use md5sum without explicitly mentioning the column, so the command that worked was this: find $1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat --format '%Y :%y %n' | sort -nr | cut -d: -f2- | awk 'BEGIN { ORS=" "} {print $1,$2,$3} {system("md5sum "$4)} '